# Number of non-isomorphic groups of order $p^n$ where $p$ prime is equal to the number of partitions of $n$

Tags: abstract-algebra, finite-groups

Number of non-isomorphic groups of order $p^n$ where $p$ prime is equal to the number of partitions of $n$ :By a partition of $n$ we shall mean $n=n_1+n_2+...+n_k;n_1\geq n_2\geq ..\geq n_k>0$

**My try:**

$G=A_1\times A_2\times ...\times A_k$ where $A_i$ is a cyclic group of order $p^{n_i}$ and $n=n_1+n_2+...+n_k;n_1\geq n_2\geq ..\geq n_k>0$

Let $\mathbb A=$number of non-isomorphic groups of order $p^n$
and $\mathbb B=$number of partitions of $n$

I want to find a bijective mapping from $\mathbb A$ to $\mathbb B$

I used $f:\mathbb A\rightarrow \mathbb B$ by $f(G)=n_1+n_2+...+n_k$

I am sure it is onto but I am not getting it injective

because if $f(G)=f(G')$ then $n_1+n_2+...+n_k=m_1+m_2+...+m_l=n$

from here how to conclude that $k=l$ and $n_i=m_i$

Any help

Answer (score -1):

you need "abelian" in the question or it is false. The idea of your proof is right, so it's not clear where your confusion is coming from (it might help if you take some of the language from set theory out and try to write more clearly).

Note that you may have to rearrange factors on both sides of your bijection.

Finally, the two different decompositions you write of the number $9$ correspond to $\mathbb{Z}/2 \times \mathbb{Z}/2 \times \mathbb{Z}/5$ vs. $\mathbb{Z}/4 \times \mathbb{Z}/5$.

Comment: is this mapping injective?

Comment: I cant prove this..

Comment: What are you missing? You need to show that if two groups are not isomorphic then the associated partitions are not the same. But if the associated partitions are the same, the groups are obviously isomorphic (just rearrange the factors if necessary).

Comment: I have $n_1+n_2+..+n_k=m_1+m_2+..+m_l$ from here how to conclude partitions are same ;is it clear now?